# Failed To Load Viewstate Error From Code Nuggets (<%= %>) In User Control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, viewstate

Very strange problem. I have a user control that I load dynamically into a page based on a condition. The instant I add a code nugget to the designer in the .ascx such as this:

```
 <%= "hello" %>
```

I get the error:

Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get around it?

Thanks so much for the help!